# what typically consumes more ram on a website?

Tags: web-development, memory-management, memory-leaks

i have a mac and im using the new firefox 4 just testing to see if it will use less ram usage than before. when i open facebook and flickr the usage flys up. what is typically sucking more ram? im guessing its javascript but maybe there is more?

just curious so that maybe i can build my web application better if the methods i already use suck ram.

Comment: php isn't going to use any ram on your client at all. This seems more like a Superuser question. Anyway javascript, page rendering, alpha's, fancy effects, rotating ads, network latency will all be things that could impact on your ram. Chrome for me seems the quickest

Comment: Media on the Website probably take quite a bit, but I would imagine the majority would be all of the Extensions/Plugins that the Browser has to load to process that Media.

Comment: Flash will suck the living cycles out of your CPU.

Comment: yea flash i know of lol its a good sucker. and wow i didntk now network latency sucks ram also. i guess the best thing to do is always optimize images to the smallest possible but still holding its quality. i heave heard that hte jquery library sucks ram as well. i havent really tested but what do you think>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things that require plugins (ie. flash) will consume more ram to run than most other content.  After that, images and executing scripting languages take up a good deal of ram.  Lastly, I would expect the html content of the page itself to take up the least amount of ram unless the page is particularly large.